# Getting an error for creating python dedicated shells

Tags: shell, ipython

Some time ago, I asked [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69539/dedicated-python-shells-that-runs-the-code) question, which is how to create new python shells that get renamed based on the script from which they are run, e.g., `foo.py` should create a shell `*Python[foo.py]*`, and `foe.py` creates `*Python[foe.py]*`. So far, that worked, but recently I needed to reinstall my OS, and hence Emacs. Now, when I try the same function, I get the error: `NameError: name '__PYTHON_EL_eval_file' is not defined`. It is the same error as [as this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71672/call-a-function-and-all-relevant-hooks-inside-a-function).

I hooked that function to `C-c C-C`. If I `C-c C-c` once the error is generated, but if I `C-c C-c` twice, then it works as expected. So, it seems by running `C-c C-c` once, the file is being generated.

This is the, according to my understanding, relevant code in my init.el file

```lisp
(require 'python)


(use-package python-mode
  :ensure t
  :hook (python-mode . lsp-deferred)
  :custom
  (python-shell-interpreter "python"))

(use-package pyvenv
  :config
  (pyvenv-mode 1))

(setq python-shell-completion-native-enable nil)

(defun my-python-start-or-switch-rep (&optional msg)
"Start and/or switch to the REPL."
(interactive "p")
(if (python-shell-get-process)
    (progn
      (python-shell-send-buffer)
      (python-shell-switch-to-shell)
      )
  (progn
    (run-python (python-shell-calculate-command) t t)
    (other-window 1)
    (python-shell-send-buffer)
    (python-shell-switch-to-shell)
    )
  )
)

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
      (lambda () (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'my-python-start-or-switch-rep))
      )
(put 'upcase-region 'disabled nil)
```

I searched the web, but didn't really find a solution; maybe the solution is simple. I am an Emacs noob, and most of my stuff is what I found online/asked and tried to change, so that's why I feel helpless. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Start with `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and try again. Does it bring any new insights? (In that case add it to the question)

Comment: I did it. Where should I see any debugging messages? I get the same error, but when `*Messages*`, and there was nothing there, or the ipython shell. I am not sure where else to search.

Comment: Update. I got an error that debugger tracked. It opened a buffer called `*Backtrace*`, however, that error is unrelated to this problem (the error was with lsp and completion). In other words, `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` is working, but somehow my problem is not triggering anything.

Comment: Okay, I guess it does not provide much useful info then. So what happens if you just do manually `M-: (run-python (python-shell-calculate-command) t t)`, then switch back to your python buffer and do `M-x python-shell-send-buffer`?

Comment: It works. I don't get any error. I guess I can adapt my code using these commands.